# Sending multiple request on facebook app

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a facebook application create via MVC .net. I'm using script to display/send request to multiple user. Now my problem is, I want the dialog to display with checkboxes not send buttons as it defeats the purpose of sending request to multiple facebook freinds. Here's a screenshot of my current request dialog.

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot. The dialog displays Invite buttons. I want it to have checkboxes and a send request button that if I click the send request button. Those that I have checked will receive requests.

Here's the code I use to display my request dialog.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        title: 'Check out LoyaltyNmore!',
        message: 'Earn loyalty points with me!',
    }, fbCallback);
```

I also added this on my FB.init

```
frictionlessRequests: true
```

All these codes were based [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). The guide says that it should display with checboxes not invite buttons. I think I'm lacking something with my code. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: As your question's title, I think you can use batch processing. Facebook supports to send **multi request in one batch**.

Comment: I'm looking for the UI with checkboxes for batch processing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. You can create custom though -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector